# Enlargement in one dimension to bigger polygon

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, field-calculator, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18

I have areas (polygon) in the streets (polygons).

[image]

I want to enlagre the parallel segment to an other polygon to touch it. And so creating this new polygons.

[image]

There is a lot of new alogithms in field calculator. Maybe processing alorithms could be a solution or Python or GRASS. I don't know which way to choose.

At this time, i try this way :

1. Cut areas by street polygons
2. Join attributes by location to grab street polygon id in the area
3. Polygon to lines
4. Explode lines
5. Maybe ** IF segment is < 0-45 degrees THEN segment is extended to road polygons ( exploded too ?)**

Polygons to lines

Comment: The green polygons are always longer in the direction of the streets than they are wide? That way we can know in which direction to enlarge them. Have you tried v.centerline to convert green areas to lines, then v.buffer with flat end caps and then clip the results with dissolved street polygons?

Comment: No they are **not** always longer in the direction of the streets than they are wide. Not yet tried. goood idea. i try

Comment: Ok. Then it might work better if you dissolve the roads, v.centerline them, clip the centerlines with the green areas and then v.buffer these centerlines (instead of the green area centerlines) with flat end cap and then clip the buffers with road polygons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, see the source data in Figure 1;
[image]
The solution is as follows:
1) In QGIS, run the Vector tool - "Geometry processing" - "Extract nodes" onto the polygon being processed, the result is shown in figure 2;

[image]

2) If you have rectangular polygons, then run in pgAdmin a query for two opposite points belonging to the polygon:

`create table exper_poi1 as
SELECT ST_ClosestPoint (my_line_exper.geom, exper_poi.geom)
FROM my_line_exper, exper_poi
WHERE exper_poi.gid = 1;`

and combine them into one layer (table), for example exper_poi_all.
(in my experiment there are 4 such points, and not 2, since I do not have a rectangular polygon), the result is shown in Figure 3;

[image]

3) In QGIS, on your exper_poi_all table, run the Delaunay Triangulation tool and get the following table, for example: exper_poi_triangl, see figure 4;

[image]

4) In QGIS in the "Pencil" editing mode in the exper_poi_triangl table, select all triangles that fall into the area of interest, use the "Vector" tool - "Geoprocessing" - "Merge by feature" (check "selected objects only" "Classification" - for all reasons) result exper_poly see figure 5;

[image]

Good luck, with respect